# HTTPS and HTTP shows different results

Tags: laravel, heroku

I'm new to Heroku and I have recently tried deploying my first Laravel project. Howerver, when I opened my app, HTTPS and HTTP yield different results. Particularly, HTTPS doesn't show the right navbar while HTTP does.

To me, this seems quite weird. This is my HTTPS page:

[image]

And my HTTP one:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer to my question. The reason is due to the disagreement of HTTP and HTTPS in routes of laravel.

Comment: I'm having the same issues, what do you mean by that?